# Knitr: Display tilde ~ in beamer overlay

Tags: latex, knitr, beamer

This might be an edge case, but I'm trying to create a beamer presentation with knitr where I want to display a code chunk using different formulas as arguments for a function. I found that when using overlays, the tilde in the code chunks disappear. Is there a way to get them to display?

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Slide with overlay}
\only<1>{
<<notilde, eval = FALSE>>=
myfunction(data, formula = ~ x)
@
}
\only<2>{
<<notilde2, eval = FALSE>>=
myfunction(data, formula = y ~ x)
@
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Slide without overlay}
<<tilde, eval = FALSE>>=
myfunction(data, formula = ~ x)
@
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The first frame of the presentation looks like this:

[image: slide with overlay]

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The slide without overlay looks like this:

[image: slide without overlay]

To clarify, the syntax of `<<...>>` and `@` is specific to the R package knitr. Anything between these symbols are interpreted by knitr as R code chunks and converted to latex to include syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the ~ with the math mode $\sim$

If not in a special environment like verbatim, the tilde in latex is a protected space, i.e. a space at which no line break occurs.

It is not clear from your question: is it working for your second frame, without overlay?
I don't know part of your syntax: is the << ... >>= ... @ equivalent to a verbatim or code environmet? It looks a bit, as your text is set in a fixed space font and has syntax highlihting.

Comment: Sorry for not having replied much earlier. I have addressed your questions in my edit. Your suggestion of using $\sim$ unfortunately does not work with this specific situation, unfortunately.